# mysql if statement with datetime

Tags: mysql

i want to select dates in datetime, but if time of startDate is more then time of endDate then add one day to endDate, here is my code, but it doesn't work, thanks

```
SELECT Schedules.*
FROM 'schedules' AS Schedules 
WHERE Schedules.active=1
AND '2013-01-21' BETWEEN DATE(Schedules.startDate) AND 
(
IF TIME(Schedules.startDate)>TIME(Schedules.endDate) THEN 
SELECT (DATE(DATE_ADD(SELECT Schedules.endDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
ELSE SELECT Schedules.endDate
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample for mysql statement. Follow http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/0752c/6

and the code if needed:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourtable` (
  `Id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Name` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `EndDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

INSERT INTO `yourtable`(`Id`,`Name`,`StartDate`,`EndDate`)
VALUES
(1, 'S1', '2013-01-03 11:23:59', '2013-01-04 13:26:12'),
(2, 'S2', '2013-01-04 00:00:00', '2013-01-04 23:59:59'),
(3, 'S3', '2013-01-12 23:59:59', '2013-01-12 22:20:25'),
(4, 'S4', '2013-01-15 18:15:15', '2013-01-17 13:20:20'),
(5, 'S5', '2013-01-20 21:23:59', '2013-01-22 19:26:12'),
(6, 'S6', '2013-01-04 11:23:59', '2013-01-20 19:26:12'),
(7, 'S7', '2013-01-04 11:23:59', '2013-01-20 08:26:12');


SELECT 
  Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate, 
  CASE WHEN TIME(StartDate) > TIME(EndDate) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS TF,
  CASE WHEN TIME(StartDate) > TIME(EndDate) THEN DATE(DATE_ADD(EndDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ELSE DATE(EndDate) END AS EndDateUp
FROM yourtable 
WHERE 
DATE('2013-01-04') BETWEEN DATE(StartDate) AND 
  CASE WHEN TIME(StartDate) > TIME(EndDate) 
  THEN DATE(DATE_ADD(EndDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
  ELSE DATE(EndDate)  END
;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has not `IF` statement, just an `IF` function. Instead of

```
IF TIME(Schedules.startDate)>TIME(Schedules.endDate) THEN 
SELECT (DATE(DATE_ADD(SELECT Schedules.endDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
ELSE SELECT Schedules.endDate
```

you could either write a proper [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) with parentheses:

```
IF(TIME(Schedules.startDate)>TIME(Schedules.endDate),
   DATE(DATE_ADD(Schedules.endDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
   Schedules.endDate)
```

or you could write a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
CASE WHEN TIME(Schedules.startDate)>TIME(Schedules.endDate)
     THEN DATE(DATE_ADD(Schedules.endDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
     ELSE Schedules.endDate
END
```

In either case, omit all those additional `SELECT` keywords, as you're not performing subqueries there, just evaluating expressions.